# VC++ 2008 Error Map/set iterator is incompatible

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, iterator

I have a project well running on VC++ 2003 .Net. But I have upgraded it to VC++ 2008 then it is compiled successfully. Now, I executed it & it crashes in the following code:

```
CString szDCode(_T("E007"), _T("****"));
map<CString, CString>::iterator itr;
itr = m_ECodes.find(szDCode);
if(itr != m_ECodes.end())
{   
  szDCode = (*itr).second;
  itr = m_LineComponents.find(szDCode);
  if(itr != m_ECodes.end()) // This line is creating Error, While I have 4-5 items in it.
    szDCode = (*itr).second;
}
```

Here the Error being generated is:
*Expression: map/set iterators incompatible.*

Plz help me.

Abhishek

Answer (score 8):

You get an iterator from the `m_LineComponents` container:

```
itr = m_LineComponents.find(szDCode);
```

You try to compare this iterator against an iterator from the `m_ECodes` container:

```
itr != m_ECodes.end()
```

You can only compare two iterators from the same container.  Newer versions of Visual C++ include checks in the Standard Library that help you to find this sort of error.  The code was never correct.